# Two foreign key in the same model from two different model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I need to put two Foreign Keys in a model class from two different models. I would like to relate the third model class to the first and the second.

I've tried something like this:

```
class A (models.Model)
    id_A = models.IntergerField (primary_key=True)
    #...

    class B (models.Model)
     id_B = models.IntergerField (primary_key=True)
    #...

    class C (models.Model)
      id_A = models.ForeignKey(A)
      id_B = models.ForeignKey(B)
```

Reading the docs I understand that is not possible to have [MultipleColumnPrimaryKeys](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/MultipleColumnPrimaryKeys)... but I Didn't receive any error from django with this models.py

Is it possible? Is there a smarter way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it well, if you were relating id_A and id_B to a same model, django would give you an error, in this case just put `related_name` attribute in the second field.

Comment: Ok, I was about to find an answer about related_name attribute, but you already answer me!! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Django didn't pop up error because you were doing it right. It's totally reasonable that there are multiple foreign keys in one model, just like class C.

In class C, as long as id_A and id_B is the single column primary keys of their own model, it will perfectly work out.

"MultipleColumnPrimaryKeys" you mentioned is a different thing. It means that for a specific table in database, there are multiple columns together to be the table's primary key, which is not supported in Django.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I'm new and I'm trying everything just now! Bye!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a many-to-many relationship that automatically creates that intermediate model for you:

```
from django.db import models


class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)


class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    publications = models.ManyToManyField(Publication, related_name='articles')
```

With this you can do both:

```
publication.articles.all()  # Gives you the articles of the current publication instance
article.publications.all()  # Gives you the publications of the current article instance
```

Check out docs for [many to many](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

If you need to use any additional fields in that intermediate model, you can tell django which is the `through` model like this:

```
from django.db import models


class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)


class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')


class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Check out docs for [extra fields on many to many](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)

Also, if you are going for a standard integer auto-increment primary key, django already generates one for you so you don't need to define `id_A` and `id_B`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, id_A and id_B are not auto-increment primary key, but UUIDField: I now realize that I didn't write correctly.